# Lambda function not Propagating HTTP 403 Error from Lambda to Frontend via GraphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm encountering an issue where my AWS Lambda function correctly returns a 403 HTTP status code, but this error is not properly propagated to the frontend through AWS AppSync and my GraphQL API. Instead of receiving a 403 error on the frontend, I get a 200 OK status with the error details embedded in the GraphQL response. I need the frontend to receive the 403 status directly for proper error handling. For better context, I am not throwing an error with a 403 status, I am simply returning the 403 error code as a result of app sync not being able to resolve the credentials in my lambda function.

Here's how my setup works:

Lambda Function: My Lambda function, integrated with AWS AppSync, checks permissions and returns an AWSError object with a statusCode of 403 when access is denied.

AWS AppSync: The Lambda function is connected to an AWS AppSync API, which is supposed to relay errors from the Lambda to the frontend.

GraphQL Schema: My GraphQL API is defined in AWS CDK and includes standard configurations for the schema and resolvers.

Frontend: The frontend application executes GraphQL queries and expects to handle HTTP status codes for errors.

All config is handled via using AWS's CDK.

My Lambda/GraphQL setup:

```
export interface ApiProps {
  searchServiceDomain: IDomain;
}

export class SearchServiceApi extends GraphqlApi {
  constructor(
    scope: AppStack,
    id: string,
    { searchServiceDomain }: ApiProps,
  ) {
    const authPoolId = StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(
      scope,
      '/Config/AuthPoolId',
    );

    super(scope, id, {
      name: addStageToName(scope, 'SearchServiceApi'),
      schema: Schema.fromAsset('./src/model/schema.graphql'),
      authorizationConfig: {
        defaultAuthorization: {
          authorizationType: AuthorizationType.USER_POOL,
          userPoolConfig: {
            userPool: UserPool.fromUserPoolId(
              scope,
              'AuthPool',
              authPoolId,
            ),
            defaultAction: UserPoolDefaultAction.ALLOW,
          },
        },
        additionalAuthorizationModes: [
          {
            authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
          },
        ],
      },
      logConfig: {
        fieldLogLevel: FieldLogLevel.ERROR,
        retention: RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH,
        excludeVerboseContent: true,
      },
      xrayEnabled: true,
    });

    this.addOpenSearchDataSource(
      'SearchServiceOpenSearchDataSource',
      searchServiceDomain,
    );

    new StringParameter(this, 'SsmSearchApiUrl', {
      parameterName: `/${addStageToName(
        scope,
        'project',
      )}/SearchApiUrl`,
      stringValue: this.graphqlUrl,
    });

    new StringParameter(this, 'SsmSearchApiId', {
      parameterName: `/${addStageToName(scope, 'project')}/SearchApiId`,
      stringValue: this.apiId,
    });
  }

  getApiUrl() {
    return this.graphqlUrl;
  }
}
```

How can I configure AWS AppSync and my GraphQL setup to ensure that the HTTP 403 status code from the Lambda function is directly relayed to the frontend, instead of being wrapped in a 200 OK response with error details in the body?

Comment: What GraphQL client are you using? The normal pattern is to return 200 with errors in the error object. Why? Because GraphQL allows you to execute multiple queries in a single request. Some may succeed while others fail. Even in a single query you can have overall success while some branches of the response tree fail.